# Why isn't my application of KVL working here

Tags: kirchhoffs-laws

Firstly, please note that this is a high school level, physics question, but as this is related to circuits, I feel this is a better place for such a question than PSE.

The image is from byjus and first appeared in jee mains 2020.
[image: source:byjus, originally from jee main 2020]

The question is to find the approximate current via the 10 V battery along with the direction.

My attempt - Let the flow be clockwise in the left hand part and anti-clockwise in the right hand part.

Let the current flowing via the left hand part be i1 and the flow via part 2 be i2.

then -20=-5i1-10(i1+i2)-2i1

and -10=-10(i1+i2)-4i2

So we get the required answer in magnitude but not in direction.

Why is my answer wrong?

Instead are the correct equations as follows?

20=-5i1-10(i1+i2)-2i1

and 10=-10(i1+i2)-4i2

Please let me know if this isn't an appropriate place for such an  elementary question.

Comment: If  anyone downvotes,please let me know why so that I can improve myself in future posts

Comment: "byjus" and "jee mains" means nothing to most of us here...

Comment: I was   just citing the  source, sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *Let the flow be clockwise in the left hand part and anti-clockwise in
> the right hand part*

Like this: -

[image]

Hence, \$20 = 5\cdot I_1 + 10\cdot(I_1+I_2) + 2\cdot I_1\$

And, \$10 = 10\cdot (I_1+I_2) + 4\cdot I_2\$

It looks like you may have stated or believed incorrectly what the current directions were.

Comment: Thanks  for the answer.,  I have a doubt in your diagram, why  is  the current in the 4ohm  resistor  flowing towards the left and  not right. Moreover, I tried solving the voltag equations and am still getting that  the current is flowing from the negative to the positive terminal, is that correct?

Comment: I haven't indicated current flow in the 4 ohm resistor. The blue arrows are the voltages (based on current flow) and I2 flows to the right in the 4 ohm resistor. A flow to the right in the 4 ohm resistor produces a positive voltage to the left of the 4 ohm resistor hence, the blue arrowhead is to the left.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you.

Comment: My answer agrees with your answer in other words so, either the "true" answer is wrong or, you have misinterpreted the current flow in the original question. Please [take the 2 minute tour](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour) to understand why folk give help for free.

Comment: I will. Thanks!